# Return Rest CompletableFuture with different Http status

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

The following method will return a list of Strings with status OK.

```
@Async
@RequestMapping(path = "/device-data/search/asyncCompletable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<?>> getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture() {
    logger.info("** start getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture **");
    // Get a future of type String
    CompletableFuture<List<String>> futureList = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> processRequest());
    return futureList.thenApply(dataList -> new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(dataList, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

I would like to make this method more robust by adding the following features:

1)  Since fetching the data will take some time ( processRequest())) than in the meanwhile I would like to return status ACCEPTED so there will be some notification for the user.

2)  In case the list is empty then I want to return status NO_CONTENT.

How can I add these enhancements in the same method?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is an `@Async` function, you're waiting for `processRequest()` to complete and `thenApply()` function takes the results and set `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` to `ResponseEntity` despite the results status.

You return that already processed result list, just like a `synchronized` invoke. I would rather let the client to decide if the `List` is empty or not, after an immediate response.

```
@Async
@RequestMapping(path = "/device-data/search/asyncCompletable", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<List<String>>> getValueAsyncUsingCompletableFuture() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> ResponseEntity.accepted().body(processRequest()));
}
```

In the client code, once the get response via `RestTemplate` of `WebClient` wait for the response or continue the rest of the tasks.

```
CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<List<String>>> response = ... // The response object, should be CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<List<String>>> type hence returns from the upstream endpoint.
System.out.println(response.get().getBody()); // 'get()' returns a instance of 'ReponseEntity<List<String>>', that's why 'getBody()' invokes.
```

Well this `CompletableFuture.get()` is a `blocking` function and it would wait the current thread until the response arrives. You can continue without `blocking` for the response until particular response is required in the code.

Comment: Thank you very much Sachith for your help. Apologized for the mistake in the main thread. I changed the HttpStatus to OK. I would prefer to return HttpStatus ACCEPTED immediately and when the processRequest is done then send the output with status OK.

Comment: Why do you expect their HTTP client to retrieve the HTTP response as `CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<List<String>>>`? And how does this satisfy the question's requirements of reading the HTTP response status/headers, doing _something_, then waiting to read the response body?

Comment: Per my understanding, In case the controller return a value then it must be of type CompletableFuture.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, How do you suppose to read the response (header/body) whatsoever, when even the response itself not processed yet? `CompletableFuture` do not give any response untill the process is completed and block for the result. The question asks for two `ResponseEntity` responses with two different status codes. Well, as I know that's impossible. If we follow the solution in the question, that makes no sense to asynchronous behavior. This is not a WebFlux implementation either to give him a reactive message chain.

Comment: You wouldn't use `CompletableFuture`. This is an HTTP server. You can send HTTP response status line and headers before you send a body. But you probably have to do it directly with an `HttpServletResponse`, not through any Spring MVC types.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help.